# Falcor Router Observable

Tags: router, observable, falcor

Having trouble using the Observable in my route. The router is not sending the pathValue to the client. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    route: 'starshipsById[{integers:starshipIds}][{keys:props}]',
    get: (pathSet) => Observable.from(pathSet.starshipIds)
        .flatMap(starshipId =>
          Observable.fromPromise(r.table('starshipsById').get(starshipId).run(c))
            .flatMap(starship => Observable.from(pathSet.props).map(key => {
              const pathValue = !starship ?
              {
                path: ['starshipsById', starship.id],
                value: null,
              } : {
                path: ['starshipsById', starship.id, key],
                value: starship[key] || null
              };
              return pathValue;
            })
        ))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was using the wrong Observable node package. I replaced the "rxjs" package with "rx" and it works fine now.